# How to upgrade hiera on PE3.8 without master remediating it back?

Tags: hiera, puppet-enterprise

We have PE3.8 with hiera v1.3.4. However, I want to upgrade hiera to v3.0.5 (using gem install hiera). When we do this, the Puppet Master automatically reverts that back to 1.3.4 after a while.

(Hiera v1.3.4 is a symlink in /usr/local/bin. After upgrade it is the v3.0.5 executable.)

What is the correct way to upgrade hiera on the Puppet Master?

Thanks, Ed

Comment: PS I can see the package resource (package { 'hiera': ensure => '1.3.4-1.el7', } ), but not sure if that's enforced via some puppet manifest somewhere? Or can I simply change that package resource?

Comment: take a look in `/opt/puppet/share/modules` or somewhere along those lines and do a `grep -r` for `hiera`.

Comment: Great, thanks. The only line that *seems* to be of interest is:
`puppet_enterprise/Gemfile.lock:    hiera (1.3.4))`
However I don't think that file should be edited, but is more a file showing what bundle installed?
Unless it comes with the PE version (3.8.2)?